# wordpress add javascript to button or image

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am looking for a method to add a java script file to a button or image within Wordpress. The script works fine and opens a screen to be subscribed to a newsletter. But I want this screen only to appear when button or image is clicked. Is there a way to do it?

Here is the script

```
<!-- Laposta 1.1 -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var Laposta = {};
Laposta.width = '200';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="subscribe.js"></script>
<!-- /Laposta -->
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated